# How to create a library that depends on OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, c++11, cmake

If I want to create a static library that depends on OpenCV, how do I do it? The idea is to make it easier for clients to link against the library I'm creating.

I'm using CMake to create the library. For me, linking against the library is not an issue.

Clients will receive my library and they will need to use it. How do I bundle OpenCV with it?

Update: For now I'm using a .so and this solves my problem. Now, is it possible to do the same thing with.a?

Comment: Perhaps specifying the build system you plan to use (make/cmake/whatever) will help you get more answers

Comment: Thanks, I just clarified the question.

Comment: You may either ship the relevant OpenCV code along with your library source or you may pre-compile OpenCV for a given architecture and use the pre-built `.so` or `.a` files within your project, However shipping the relevant OpenCV code seems to be a good idea, because in this  case you will have the flexibility to compile your library for any architecture.

Comment: @ZdaR: Unfortunately the code is not open source.

Comment: How does that matters? @arhuaco